# Update these record using single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my friend recently went to an interview and he was asked this question there and i'm also not able to give an answer to this.

This was the question:
Update Female as Male and Male as Female using single query in MS SQL

```
Name   Gender  Salary 
A       M      10000
B       M      20000
C       F      30000
D       F      40000
E       M      20000
F       M      10000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update your_table
set gender = case when gender = 'F' 
                  then 'M'
                  else 'F' 
             end
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0c8640/1)